# firefox browser is not opening with build.xml with selenium webdriver code

Tags: firefox, ant, build, webdriver

Below is the my code,

```
@Before
public void launchApplication() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "D:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe");
    System.err.println("In launch application, before launching firefox");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(testURL);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

When the above code is executed using the junit test, application (testURL) is opening successfully and my test ran successfully.

However, if the same is launched using the build.xml (ant xml), firefox is not getting launched, and in the console i can see only this message "In launch application, before launching firefox". nothing is happening after.

Help me in this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the error is being thrown because the application is not running when you launch selenium?

For example, I have  a example ANT code that launches firefox from ANT, but first waits for the web app to become available on the HTTP port:

```
<parallel>
    <jetty tempDirectory="${work.dir}">
        <connectors>
            <selectChannelConnector port="${jetty.port}"/>
        </connectors>
        <webApp name="dwr" warfile="${lib.dir}/dwr-demo-${dwr.version}.war" contextpath="/dwr"/>
    </jetty>

    <sequential>
        <waitfor>
            <socket server="localhost" port="${jetty.port}"/>
        </waitfor>
        <exec executable="firefox" spawn="yes">
            <arg line="http://localhost:${jetty.port}/dwr"/>
        </exec>
    </sequential>
</parallel>
```

Perhaps you need to emulate this logic, unless your unit tests are already launching the app?